# Ajax request to return module setup data

Tags: javascript

I have looked at various questions that talk about when Synchronous requests, how to return data from the Ajax request (with Promises and Callbacks) but nothing seems to answer what I am after.

```
var FacadeApi = ( function($) {

    var endpoint = '/auth/',
        self = this,
        settings = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        authkey: null
    };

    function init() {

        $.ajax( {
            url: self.endpoint,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true
        })
        .done( function( `enter code here`data ) {
            self.settings.authKey = data.authKey;

            self.settings.isAuthenticated = true;
        })
        .fail( function( error ) {

        });
    }

    var Facade = {

        someRequest: function( ) {

            $.ajax( {
                url: someUri,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { authKey: authKey }
            })
            .done( fuction( data ) {
                // does stuff.
            });
        }

    };

    init();

    return Facade;
}( jQuery ));
```

My module depends on requesting an authentication key and then having that as part of each request.  Until this request is resolved, it can't be used.  Which lead me to the async: false in the init function.

In this scenario, is it recommended to 'block' until the init call is completed? Could I achieve what I am after and keep the init request asynchronous?

Comment: Synchronous requests [are now deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) (at least non-worker ones), and some browsers are issuing warnings in the console when they are encountered (and may start throwing exceptions at some undetermined point) - I would attempt to avoid them at all costs

Comment: I would suggest to implement a queue, so the requests in `someRequest` would have to wait until the authKey is presented and only then executed.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand correctly,

You want to make sure that if someone calls somerequest() it should wait till you have the token , which is initiated in a separate request.

I suggest following pattern.

Do not call init() from the beginning.

when you need to call somerequest()

check if you have valid token value.

If token value is not there you can use $.When() such that somerequest() is only called when init() ajax call returns successfully.